# Why mysql is removing slash from data?

Tags: php, mysql

Using simple function:

```
mysqli_query($link, 'update  table set field = \'variable text with \" slash\' ');
$res = mysqli_query($link, 'select field from table');
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
```

when printing the result I have string without slash like: 'variable text with " slash'.
When I preview the table in my localhost mysql client (SequelPro) I see that there are no slash also.
Is it normal that mysql is removing this slash on insert automaticaly? Is it a way to prevent this? I need this slash there. Also I cannot use addslashes later after getting the value from db.
Magic quotes are disabled on my php server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The slashes you are adding are used to escape the quotes in the php string. You should add 3 slashes `\\\"` so that the first two make a backslash and the third one escapes the quote.

Comment: But it's NOT Mysql removing them. it's php taking them as escape-characters for the following character.

Comment: No, the single quotes should not be escaped. They are needed to denote a string in the MySQL query.

Comment: Used wrong quote. Should be the double quote with 3 quotes before it.

Answer (score 2):

This is because PHP is escaping the `"`. You need to escape the backslash too, like this:

```
mysqli_query($link, 'update  table set field = \'variable text with \\\" slash\' ');
```

Or you could use [addslashes()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php).

```
$query = addslashes('update  table set field = \'variable text with \" slash\' ')
mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to keep the second backslash, as the first and third are needed to escape the single quotes. To keep the backslash, simply escape the backslash:

```
mysqli_query($link, 'update  table set field = \'variable text with \\" slash\' ');
```

You don't need to escape the double quote because this string is enclosed by single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use double slach `\\`

try that:

```
mysqli_query($link, "update  table set field = 'variable text with \\" slash' ");
```